# Problemas con Arreglos y Objetos

Tags: array, poo, objeto, class, diseño-de-clases

El inconveniente es el siguiete, tengo una clase usuarioDonador y usuarioDonatario. El usuarioDonatario puede crear uno o varios programas de donaciones. Y el usuarioDonador puede hacer uno o varias donaciones en efectivo. El problema es el siguiente, existe una relacion entre la donacion y el programaDonacion, un programa puede recibir varias donaciones, mientras que una donacion va a un programa en especifico. Quiero saber la manera de guardar por ejemplo: la donacion[0] en el programaDonacion[0] del usuarioDonatario[0]. No estoy seguro como setear este dato en el programa de Donacion del usuario correcto. Adjunto mando el codigo!

Clase Principal

```
package proyectofinal;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Variables Compartidas
        String telefono, correo = null, clave = null;
        //Variables Donante
        String nombreDonador, apellidoDonador, cedula;
        //Variables Donatario
        String nombreInstitucion, ruc, direccion;

        //Variables Auxiliares
        int aux1 = 0, i = 0, iDonante = 0, iDonatario = 0;
        //Inicializacion de los objetos
        UsuarioDonante donantes[] = new UsuarioDonante[20];
        UsuarioDonatario donatarios[] = new UsuarioDonatario[20];
        //QUEMADO DE DATOS
        //UsuarioDonante
        donantes[0] = new UsuarioDonante("John", "Smith", "1700049235", "0983387777", "john@gmail.com", "1234");
        
        //UsuarioDonatario
        donatarios[0] = new UsuarioDonatario("Institucion1", "1234567890123", "Quito", "0999999494", "institucion@gmail.com", "4444");

        //Menu de Opciones
        do {
            System.out.println("-----INICIO DE SESION-----");
            System.out.println("1. Ingresar Sesion como Donante");
            System.out.println("2. Ingresar Sesion como Donatario");
            System.out.println("3. Salir");
            System.out.println("Ingresar una de las opciones: ");

            try {
                aux1 = sc.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Ingresar solo valores numericos!");
                sc.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
                sc.nextLine();
            }

            switch (aux1) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("-----INICIO DE SESION COMO DONANTE-----");

                    //Ingreso del Correo
                    sc.nextLine();
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese su correo electronico: ");
                        correo = sc.nextLine();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR!");
                        sc.nextLine();
                    }

                    //Ingreso de la Clave
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese su clave: ");
                        clave = sc.nextLine();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR!");
                        sc.nextLine();
                    }

                    //Verificacion de los datos para iniciar sesion
                    for (i = 0; i < donantes.length; i++) {
                        try {
                            if (correo.equals(donantes[i].getCorreo()) && clave.equals(donantes[i].getClave())) {
                                System.out.println("Inicio de Sesion Exitoso!");
                                inicioSesionDonante(donantes, i, donatarios);
                                break;
                            }
                        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                            System.out.println("No se pudo iniciar sesion. Verificar los datos ingresados!");
                            sc.nextLine();
                            break;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR!");
                            sc.nextLine();
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("-----INICIO DE SESION COMO DONATARIO-----");

                    //Ingreso del Correo
                    sc.nextLine();
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese su correo electronico: ");
                        correo = sc.nextLine();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR!");
                        sc.nextLine();
                    }

                    //Ingreso de la Clave
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese su clave: ");
                        clave = sc.nextLine();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR!");
                        sc.nextLine();
                    }

                    //Verificacion de los datos para iniciar sesion
                    for (i = 0; i < donatarios.length; i++) {
                        try {
                            if (correo.equals(donatarios[i].getCorreo()) && clave.equals(donatarios[i].getClave())) {
                                System.out.println("Inicio de Sesion Exitoso!");
                                inicioSesionDonatario(donatarios, i);
                                break;
                            }
                        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                            System.out.println("No se pudo iniciar sesion. Verificar los datos ingresados!");
                            sc.nextLine();

                            break;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR!");
                            sc.nextLine();
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Ha salido de la aplicacion exitosamente");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Ingresar una opcion valida!");
                    break;

            }

        } while (aux1 != 3);

    }

    public static void inicioSesionDonante(UsuarioDonante[] donante, int i, UsuarioDonatario[] donatario) {
        //Scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Variables
        double cantidadDinero = 0;
        String nombreInstitucion = null;
        //Variables auxiliares
        int aux1 = 0, iDonatario = 0;

        System.out.println("Bienvenido " + donante[i].getNombre() + " " + donante[i].getApellido() + "!\n");

        do {
            //Menu de opciones del donante
            System.out.println("-----MENU DE OPCIONES-----");
            System.out.println("1. Visualizar Informacion Personal: ");
            System.out.println("2. Donar en Efectivo");
            System.out.println("3. Donar Productos");
            System.out.println("4. ");
            System.out.println("5. Cerrar Sesion");
            System.out.println("Ingresar una de las opciones: ");

            try {
                aux1 = sc.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Ingresar solo valores numericos!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
            }

            switch (aux1) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("-----VISUALIZAR INFORMACION PERSONAL-----");
                    donante[i].visualizarInfoPersonal();

                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("-----DONAR EN EFECTIVO-----");


                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Ha cerrado sesion con exito!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Ingresar una opcion valida!");
                    break;

            }
        } while (aux1 != 5);

    }

    public static void inicioSesionDonatario(UsuarioDonatario[] donatario, int i) {
        //Scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Variables ProgramaDonacion
        String nombrePrograma = null;
        TipoDonacion tipoDonacion = null;
        int diaLimite = 0, mesLimite = 0, anioLimite = 0;

        //Variables Auxiliares
        int aux1 = 0, aux2 = 0;

        System.out.println("Bienvenido!\n");

        do {
            //Menu de opciones del donatario
            System.out.println("-----MENU DE OPCIONES-----");
            System.out.println("1. Visualizar Informacion Institucional");
            System.out.println("2. Agregar Programa de Donaciones");
            System.out.println("3. Visualizar Programas Creados");
            System.out.println("4. ");
            System.out.println("5. Cerrar Sesion");
            System.out.println("Ingresar una de las opciones: ");

            try {
                aux1 = sc.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Ingresar solo valores numericos!");
                sc.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
                sc.nextLine();
            }

            switch (aux1) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("-----VISUALIZAR INFORMACION INSTITUCIONAL-----");
                    donatario[i].visualizarInfoInstitucional();

                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("-----AGREGAR PROGRAMA DE DONACIONES-----");

                    //Ingreso del nombre del programa
                    sc.nextLine();
                    do {
                        System.out.println("Ingresar el nombre del programa de donaciones: ");
                        try {
                            nombrePrograma = sc.nextLine();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR!");
                            sc.nextLine();
                        }

                        if (nombrePrograma.equals("")) {
                            System.out.println("Ingresar un dato valido!");
                        }

                    } while (nombrePrograma.equals(""));

                    //Ingreso del tipo de progama
                    do {
                        System.out.println("-----TIPO DE DONACION ACEPTADA-----");
                        System.out.println("1.Efectivo\n2.Productos Basicos");
                        System.out.println("Ingresar una de las opciones: ");
                        try {
                            aux2 = sc.nextInt();

                            switch (aux2) {
                                case 1:
                                    tipoDonacion = TipoDonacion.EFECTIVO;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    tipoDonacion = TipoDonacion.PRODUCTOS;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    System.out.println("Ingresar una opcion valida!");
                                    break;

                            }
                        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR: Ingresar solo numeros!");
                            sc.nextLine();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR!");
                            sc.nextLine();
                        }

                    } while (aux2 <= 0 || aux2 >= 3);

                    //Ingreso de la fecha limite
                    System.out.println("-----INGRESAR LA FECHA LIMITE DEL PROGRAMA-----");

                    //Ingreso del dia
                    do {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Ingrese el dia: ");
                            diaLimite = sc.nextInt();
                        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR: Ingresar solo numeros!");
                            sc.nextLine();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR!");
                            sc.nextLine();

                        }

                        if (diaLimite <= 0 || diaLimite > 31) {
                            System.out.println("Ingrese un dia valido!");
                        }

                    } while (diaLimite <= 0 || diaLimite > 31);

                    //Ingreso del Mes 
                    do {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Ingrese el mes: ");
                            mesLimite = sc.nextInt();
                        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR: Ingresar solo numeros!");
                            sc.nextLine();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR!");
                            sc.nextLine();

                        }

                        if (mesLimite <= 0 || mesLimite > 12) {
                            System.out.println("Ingrese un mes valido!");
                        }

                    } while (mesLimite <= 0 || mesLimite > 12);

                    //Ingreso del Anio
                    do {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Ingrese el anio: ");
                            anioLimite = sc.nextInt();
                        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR: Ingresar solo numeros!");
                            sc.nextLine();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR!");
                            sc.nextLine();

                        }

                        if (anioLimite <= 2021) {
                            System.out.println("Ingrese un anio valido!");
                        }

                    } while (anioLimite <= 2021);

                    //Creacion de Calendar
                    switch (mesLimite) {
                        case 1:
                            Calendar fechaLimite0 = new GregorianCalendar(anioLimite, Calendar.JANUARY, diaLimite);
                            //Invocar al metodo agregarPrograma
                            donatario[i].agregarPrograma(nombrePrograma, tipoDonacion, fechaLimite0);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Calendar fechaLimite1 = new GregorianCalendar(anioLimite, Calendar.FEBRUARY, diaLimite);
                            //Invocar al metodo agregarPrograma
                            donatario[i].agregarPrograma(nombrePrograma, tipoDonacion, fechaLimite1);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Calendar fechaLimite2 = new GregorianCalendar(anioLimite, Calendar.MARCH, diaLimite);
                            //Invocar al metodo agregarPrograma
                            donatario[i].agregarPrograma(nombrePrograma, tipoDonacion, fechaLimite2);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Calendar fechaLimite3 = new GregorianCalendar(anioLimite, Calendar.APRIL, diaLimite);
                            //Invocar al metodo agregarPrograma
                            donatario[i].agregarPrograma(nombrePrograma, tipoDonacion, fechaLimite3);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Calendar fechaLimite4 = new GregorianCalendar(anioLimite, Calendar.MAY, diaLimite);
                            //Invocar al metodo agregarPrograma
                            donatario[i].agregarPrograma(nombrePrograma, tipoDonacion, fechaLimite4);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            Calendar fechaLimite5 = new GregorianCalendar(anioLimite, Calendar.JUNE, diaLimite);
                            //Invocar al metodo agregarPrograma
                            donatario[i].agregarPrograma(nombrePrograma, tipoDonacion, fechaLimite5);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            Calendar fechaLimite6 = new GregorianCalendar(anioLimite, Calendar.JULY, diaLimite);
                            //Invocar al metodo agregarPrograma
                            donatario[i].agregarPrograma(nombrePrograma, tipoDonacion, fechaLimite6);
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            Calendar fechaLimite7 = new GregorianCalendar(anioLimite, Calendar.AUGUST, diaLimite);
                            //Invocar al metodo agregarPrograma
                            donatario[i].agregarPrograma(nombrePrograma, tipoDonacion, fechaLimite7);

                            break;
                        case 9:
                            Calendar fechaLimite8 = new GregorianCalendar(anioLimite, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, diaLimite);
                            //Invocar al metodo agregarPrograma
                            donatario[i].agregarPrograma(nombrePrograma, tipoDonacion, fechaLimite8);
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            Calendar fechaLimite9 = new GregorianCalendar(anioLimite, Calendar.OCTOBER, diaLimite);
                            //Invocar al metodo agregarPrograma
                            donatario[i].agregarPrograma(nombrePrograma, tipoDonacion, fechaLimite9);
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            Calendar fechaLimite10 = new GregorianCalendar(anioLimite, Calendar.NOVEMBER, diaLimite);
                            //Invocar al metodo agregarPrograma
                            donatario[i].agregarPrograma(nombrePrograma, tipoDonacion, fechaLimite10);
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            Calendar fechaLimite11 = new GregorianCalendar(anioLimite, Calendar.DECEMBER, diaLimite);
                            //Invocar al metodo agregarPrograma
                            donatario[i].agregarPrograma(nombrePrograma, tipoDonacion, fechaLimite11);
                            break;

                    }

                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("-----VISUALIZAR PROGRAMAS CREADOS-----");
                    donatario[i].visualizarProgramas();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Ha cerrado sesion con exito!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Ingresar una opcion valida!");
                    break;

            }
        } while (aux1 != 5);
    }

}
```

Clase UsuarioDonatario

```
package proyectofinal;

import java.util.Calendar;
import static proyectofinal.TipoDonacion.EFECTIVO;

public class UsuarioDonatario extends Usuario {

    //Atributos
    private String nombreInstitucion;
    private String ruc;
    private String direccion;
    private ProgramaDonacion[] programaDonacion = new ProgramaDonacion[10];

    //Constructor
    public UsuarioDonatario(String nombreInstitucion, String ruc, String direccion, String telefono, String correo, String clave) {
        super(telefono, correo, clave);
        this.nombreInstitucion = nombreInstitucion;
        this.ruc = ruc;
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setNombreInstitucion(String nombreInstitucion) {
        this.nombreInstitucion = nombreInstitucion;
    }

    public void setRuc(String ruc) {
        this.ruc = ruc;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public void setProgramaDonacion(ProgramaDonacion[] programaDonacion) {
        this.programaDonacion = programaDonacion;
    }

    //Getters
    public String getNombreInstitucion() {
        return nombreInstitucion;
    }

    public String getRuc() {
        return ruc;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public ProgramaDonacion[] getProgramaDonacion() {
        return programaDonacion;
    }

    //Metodos
    public void visualizarInfoInstitucional() {
        System.out.println("Institucion: " + nombreInstitucion);
        System.out.println("RUC: " + ruc);
        System.out.println("Direccion: " + direccion);
        System.out.println("Telefono: " + super.getTelefono());
        System.out.println("Correo: " + super.getCorreo());
        System.out.println("Clave: " + super.getClave());
    }

    public void agregarPrograma(String nombrePrograma, TipoDonacion tipoDonacion, Calendar fechaLimite) {
        int i = buscarPrograma();

        if (i != -1) {
            programaDonacion[i] = new ProgramaDonacion(nombrePrograma, tipoDonacion, fechaLimite);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ya no se pueden crear mas programas!");
        }
    }

    public void visualizarProgramas() {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < programaDonacion.length; i++) {
            if (programaDonacion[i] != null) {
                System.out.println("-----PROGRAMA " + (i + 1) + "-----");
                System.out.println("Nombre del Programa:" + programaDonacion[i].getNombrePrograma());
                System.out.println("Tipo de Porgrama: " + programaDonacion[i].getTipoDonacion());
                System.out.println("Fecha Limite: " + programaDonacion[i].getFechaLimite().get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + programaDonacion[i].getFechaLimite().get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + programaDonacion[i].getFechaLimite().get(Calendar.YEAR));

            } else if (i == 0) {
                System.out.println("No hay programas en el sistema!");
                break;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public void visualizarProgramasEfectivo() {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < programaDonacion.length; i++) {
            try {
                if (programaDonacion[i].getTipoDonacion().equals(EFECTIVO)) {
                    System.out.println("-----PROGRAMA " + (i + 1) + "-----");
                    System.out.println("Nombre del Programa:" + programaDonacion[i].getNombrePrograma());
                    System.out.println("Fecha Limite: " + programaDonacion[i].getFechaLimite().get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + programaDonacion[i].getFechaLimite().get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + programaDonacion[i].getFechaLimite().get(Calendar.YEAR));
                } else {
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            }

        }

    }

    //Metodos Auxiliares
    public int buscarPrograma() {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < programaDonacion.length; i++) {
            if (programaDonacion[i] == null) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Clase UsuarioDonante

```
package proyectofinal;

public class UsuarioDonante extends Usuario {

    //Atributos
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String cedula;
    private DonacionEfectivo[] donacionEfectivo = new DonacionEfectivo[50];
    private DonacionProductos[] donacionProductos = new DonacionProductos[50];

    //Constructor
    public UsuarioDonante(String nombre, String apellido, String cedula, String telefono, String correo, String clave) {
        super(telefono, correo, clave);
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public void setCedula(String cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

    public void setDonacionEfectivo(DonacionEfectivo[] donacionEfectivo) {
        this.donacionEfectivo = donacionEfectivo;
    }

    public void setDonacionProductos(DonacionProductos[] donacionProductos) {
        this.donacionProductos = donacionProductos;
    }

    //Getters
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public String getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }

    public DonacionEfectivo[] getDonacionEfectivo() {
        return donacionEfectivo;
    }

    public DonacionProductos[] getDonacionProductos() {
        return donacionProductos;
    }

    //Metodos
    public void visualizarInfoPersonal() {
        System.out.println("Nombre: " + nombre + " " + apellido);
        System.out.println("Cedula: " + cedula);
        System.out.println("Telefono: " + super.getTelefono());
        System.out.println("Correo: " + super.getCorreo());
        System.out.println("Clave: " + super.getClave());
    }

    public void agregarDonacionEfectivo(double cantidad) {
        int i = buscarDonacionEfectivo();

        if (i != -1) {
            donacionEfectivo[i] = new DonacionEfectivo(cantidad);
            //donacionEfectivo[i].getProgramaDonacion().setDonacionesEfectivo(donacionEfectivo);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ya no se puede realizar mas donaciones!");
        }
    }

    //Metodos Auxiliares
    public int buscarDonacionEfectivo() {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < donacionEfectivo.length; i++) {
            if (donacionEfectivo[i] == null) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Clase DonacionEfectivo

```
package proyectofinal;

public class DonacionEfectivo {

    //Atributos
    private double cantidad;
    private UsuarioDonante usuarioDonante;
    private ProgramaDonacion programaDonacion;

    //Constructor
    public DonacionEfectivo(double cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setCantidad(double cantidad) {
        if (cantidad > 0.0) {
            this.cantidad = cantidad;
        }

    }

    public void setUsuarioDonante(UsuarioDonante usuarioDonante) {
        this.usuarioDonante = usuarioDonante;
    }

    public void setProgramaDonacion(ProgramaDonacion programaDonacion) {
        this.programaDonacion = programaDonacion;
    }

    //Getters
    public double getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public UsuarioDonante getUsuarioDonante() {
        return usuarioDonante;
    }

    public ProgramaDonacion getProgramaDonacion() {
        return programaDonacion;
    }

}
```

Clase ProgramaDonacion

```
package proyectofinal;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class ProgramaDonacion {

    //Atributos
    private String nombrePrograma;
    private TipoDonacion tipoDonacion;
    private Calendar fechaLimite;
    private UsuarioDonatario usuarioDonatario;
    private DonacionEfectivo[] donacionesEfectivo;
    private DonacionProductos[] donacionesProductos;

    //Constructor
    public ProgramaDonacion(String nombrePrograma, TipoDonacion tipoDonacion, Calendar fechaLimite) {
        this.nombrePrograma = nombrePrograma;
        this.tipoDonacion = tipoDonacion;
        this.fechaLimite = fechaLimite;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setNombrePrograma(String nombrePrograma) {
        this.nombrePrograma = nombrePrograma;
    }

    public void setTipoDonacion(TipoDonacion tipoDonacion) {
        this.tipoDonacion = tipoDonacion;
    }

    public void setFechaLimite(Calendar fechaLimite) {
        this.fechaLimite = fechaLimite;
    }

    public void setUsuarioDonatario(UsuarioDonatario usuarioDonatario) {
        this.usuarioDonatario = usuarioDonatario;
    }

    public void setDonacionesEfectivo(DonacionEfectivo[] donacionesEfectivo) {
        this.donacionesEfectivo = donacionesEfectivo;
    }

    public void setDonacionesProductos(DonacionProductos[] donacionesProductos) {
        this.donacionesProductos = donacionesProductos;
    }

    //Getters
    public String getNombrePrograma() {
        return nombrePrograma;
    }

    public TipoDonacion getTipoDonacion() {
        return tipoDonacion;
    }

    public Calendar getFechaLimite() {
        return fechaLimite;
    }

    public UsuarioDonatario getUsuarioDonatario() {
        return usuarioDonatario;
    }

    public DonacionEfectivo[] getDonacionesEfectivo() {
        return donacionesEfectivo;
    }

    public DonacionProductos[] getDonacionesProductos() {
        return donacionesProductos;
    }


}
```

Comment: No esta mal que hayas puesto todo el codigo, pero mucho del codigo no sirve para lo que estas preguntando (todos los set y los get de las clases son superfluos, todo tu menu tambien). Aca basicamente pareces tener un problema de que a alguna clase le falta un dato? la donacion, tiene que saber de quien viene no? en una base de datos tendrias una tabla intermedia con una relacion donacion donante... aca, lo podes implementar como quieras...